# Theory about accessing and modifing attributes from inner class

Tags: java, android

I have a java (android) question. 
I have a class (Class A) with its attributes and I have created private classes (Class B and C) inside of class A. Class B and C are AsyncTask.. I don't know if that's important.

I can read the attributes of ClassA from B and C, but, what happen if I modify attribute A from B or C?? I think that these changes are not being permanents,, what it's weird to me because I can access them... So, if I want that the changes are permanents I have to do from ClassB something like,,, classA.atrributeA = atributeA;

I don't know if it's because I'm working with AsyncTask,, or it's the normal behavior. I think that I have some problems with concepts...

Thank you

Comment: You can access/modify any public attribute from any other class. Why are you confusing it with inner classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think that these changes are not being permanent

That is not correct.  Changes made to an `A` instance's attribute from the nested classes are no different to changes made in other ways.

If they don't *appear* to be working as you expect, maybe the nested class instances belong to a different instance of `A` than the one you are looking at.  But that is speculation.

Anyway, if you have some concrete "unexpected behaviour" you will need to describe it ... and preferably provide an SSCCE ... if you want us to provide an explanation.

Comment: Your guys are right,, It wasn't working because in the first version I create an attribute in ClassB with the same name than in ClassA... Arggggg!!!!. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It will work. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5770638/1127492

The real issue is, whether you want to modify these attributes from the inner class as well as the outer class. I recommend to not do that because it will lead to unexpected results if two writers modify the same attribute synchronously. That's why there is a preference option in Eclipse to restrict this access.